# Android: GPS is giving last saved location

Tags: android, gps

I am working on getting current location through GPS. But GPS is always giving me last saved location! 
May be it is because of this line! I am looking for better solution!

> locationManager
>                                       .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

**Here is Sample Code**

```
if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: yes because you are using the getLastKnownLocation which returns the last known location

Comment: Pramod, to get location from LocationManager there is only 'locationManager.getLastKnownLocation()' present. Andi you can use 'LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER' instead 'LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER'.

Comment: @NikitaShah I tried LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER also...  but that also didn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
locationManager .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

it will only return the last location saved by the GPS internally.

as you have already added a listner you can get the next changed location on the `onLocationChanged` overrided function which will be the closest location you need.

There is no way rather than this you need to wait till the `onLocationChanged` function to be triggered automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Easy implementation is for you that you need to take an location listener

Don't forget to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

You can get the frequent update of location change in below listener.

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        //your code here
                     if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
    }
};
```

you  have to registered it in on create

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,    LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME,
                    LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
               //first time you can take the value from the lastKnown location 
               if (locationManager != null) {
               Location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

 }
```